# Have abled to vs have been able to

Tags: sentence-structure

1.I have abled to do that.

2. I have been able to do that.

Why we can't say 1

Answer (score 2):

As an adjective, *able* generally only takes three forms: *able*, *abler*, and *ablest*.

From [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/able):

> **1 a** : having sufficient power, skill, or resources to do something
>   // *able* to solve a problem
>
> **2** : **abler**\ -​b(ə-​)lər\; **ablest**\ -​b(ə-​)ləst\ : marked by intelligence, knowledge, skill, or competence

Although it's more common to use *more able* or *most able*, the following are still possible:

> Of the two, he is the abler.
>   She is the ablest person there.

But since it is not a verb, and not something you can conjugate as a verb, it has no past tense.

That makes *I have abled* ungrammatical:

> ✘ *I have* ***abled*** to do that.

---

Note that there is a *specific* idiomatic usage that allows for the use of *abled*. However, it's still only used adjectivally, not verbally, and only, as far as I know, in this single context.

It's become common to talk about *differently* ***abled*** people in politically correct language that tries to avoid using the word *handicapped*.

---

There is, however, a verb that's similar to *able*, and which could be substituted in the first sentence in the question:

> ✔ *I have **enabled** myself* to do that.

*Enable* is a verb that can be conjugated with a past-tense form. It is also a transitive verb, so in the example sentence a noun or pronoun needs to follow its use.

From [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/enable):

> **1 a** : to provide with the means or opportunity
>   // training that *enables* people to earn a living
>   **1 b** : to make possible, practical, or easy
>   // a deal that would *enable* passage of a new law
>   **1 c** : to cause to operate
>   // software that *enables* the keyboard

---

Note, however, that the meaning of *enable* is different from the meaning of *able*—and not just because one is a verb while the other is an adjective.

Answer (score 0):

The word "able" isn't used as a verb, so it doesn't have a past participle. The word "able" is used as an adjective:

> I'm able to play tennis
>
> I able to play tennis  (not correct)

Then perfect form "I have been able" follows.